# ВК бот не отвечает

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

пишу бота для ВК на php и развёртываю его не heroku. 
Но на сообщения он не отвечает, хотя CallBack API не ругается

```
<?php

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

// Register the monolog logging service

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(

  'monolog.logfile' => 'php://stderr',

));

$app->get('/', function() use($app){

    return('hi');

});

$app->post('/bot', function() use($app) {

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

  if(!$data) return 'huh';

  if( $data->secret != getenv('VK_CONF_KEY') && $data->type != 'confirmation') 

return 'ahah';

if($data->secret == getenv('VK_SECRET_TOKEN'))

{

  switch( $data->type)

  {

    case 'confirmation':

        return getenv('VK_CONF_KEY');

        break;

    case 'message_new':

    $request_params = array(

        'from_id' => $data->object->user_id,

        'message' => 'Test',

        'access_token' => getenv('VK_TOKEN'),

        'v' => '5.69'

    );

    file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' .
 http_build_query($request_params));

    return 'ok';

    break;

    case 'message_typing_state':

    $rquest_params = array(

        'user_id' => $data->object->user_id,

        'message' => 'YTNTCN',

        'access_token' => getenv('VK_TOKEN'),

        'v' => '5.87'

    );

    file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . http_build_query($rquest_params));

    return 'ok';

    break;

    }

}

  return "hello world";

});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, блок с кодом. Перед каждой строкой должно быть минимум 4 пробела. Проверьте, правильное ли значение хранится в VK_TOKEN . Можно узнать, отправилось ли сообщение, обернув file_get_contents в var_dump. Исходя из ответа действовать дальше.

Comment: ВК msaage_new отправляет, что видно в логах CallBack API и логах heroku, VK_TOKEN хранит в себе правильное значение file_get_contents обернул в var_dump. ничего не произошло

Comment: Расставьте echo с произвольными сообщениями в начале и в ключевых местах кода. Далее отправьте боту сообщение, которое он получит и обработает в case message_new . Если правильно настроен callback, то Вы должны увидеть вывод echo и var_dump в логах. Если нет, то скорее всего проблема не в этом алгоритме, а в то, как он запускается и правильно ли настроен callback.